# Convert Type Level List to a Value

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-level-computation

The module GHC.TypeLits currently provides `natVal` and `symbolVal`, which allow us to get a runtime value from a type of kind `Nat` or `Symbol`. Is there a way to get a runtime value of type `[String]` out of a type of kind `'[Symbol]`? I can't see an obvious way to do this. I can think of one that uses a typeclass with `OverlappingInstances`, but it seems like GHC should already have a function for this.

Comment: Are you interested in something like `forall (xs :: [Symbol]) -> HList xs -> [String]` or `forall (xs :: [Symbol]) -> Proxy xs -> [String]`. The former is simple, the latter is slightly less simple (you'll need a type class constraint on xs).

Comment: I'm looking for the latter. Although I'd be intrigued to see how the former is done as well (but it seems to me that kind `HList (xs :: '[Symbol])` is more like a list of lists). Also, I've never seen the `forall` used quite like that. Isn't there supposed to be a period after the thing it quantifies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`symbolVal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:symbolVal) can be mapped onto type level lists. To do so we'll need `ScopedTypeVariables` and `PolyKinds` in addition to `DataKinds` and `TypeOperators`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits
```

We'll defined the class of types (of any kind) for which we can "get a runtime value of type `[String]`".

```
class SymbolVals a where
    symbolVals :: proxy a -> [String]
```

We can get a list of strings for any empty list of types.

```
instance SymbolVals '[] where
    symbolVals _ = []
```

We can get a list of strings for any list of types where we can get a string for the first type and a list of strings for the remainder.

```
instance (KnownSymbol h, SymbolVals t) => SymbolVals (h ': t) where
    symbolVals _ = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy h) : symbolVals (Proxy :: Proxy t)
```

Comment: Ah, very good. I forgot that this wouldn't be a scenario that required `OverlappingInstances` because the types `'[]` and `(h ': t)` don't overlap. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `singletons` library. You have all that you need but using `Sing` instead of `Proxy` type:

```
$ stack ghci --package singletons
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds 
Prelude> import Data.Singletons.Prelude
Prelude Data.Singletons.Prelude> fromSing (sing :: Sing '["a","b"])
["a","b"]
Prelude Data.Singletons.Prelude> :t fromSing (sing :: Sing '["a","b"])
fromSing (sing :: Sing '["a","b"]) :: [String]
```